# Creating custom column with IF statement ignoring the nulls

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I've got a table of data with the column Days in Arrears, this starts at 0 and increases.
There are however fields that contain null which must be left as is.

I've created a custom column in power query with the following M-Code, but the null is being categorized under "In Arrears" which I don't want.

Is there anything that I can add to this syntax that will achieve what I am looking for?

```
if [Days In Arrears] = 0 
then "No Arrears" 
else "In Arrears")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand your code to handle `null` cases in your `Days In Arrears` column. In clear text, just nest an `if then else` that picks up `null`:

```
if [Days In Arrears] = null 
then null
else if [Days In Arrears] = 0 
then "No Arrears" 
else "In Arrears"
```

Replace your `null` in `then null` with whatever you want to display.

Comment: Don't forget about null coalesce

Comment: The null coalescing operator is nice if you want to treat nulls as zeros - but OP writes the nulls  `must be left as is`. So without a sample of the data and desired result I just assumed they did not want nulls to be "translated" :)

Comment: Fair enough - good answer. BTW, ?? can be anything rather than just zero but I'm sure you know that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ?? null coalesce operator as follows:

```
if ([Days In Arrears] ?? 0) = 0 
then "No Arrears" 
else "In Arrears"
```